# DataTables pagination plugin for input not working

Tags: jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I am trying to use input plugin of DataTables for the pagination. I have all three jar files loaded - jQuery1.11.1, dataTables1.10 and input.js. But still I am getting

```
TypeError: $.fn.dataTableExt is undefined
```

and

```
TypeError: plugin is undefined
```

errors.

Do I have to include any other jar? In some old post I saw plugin.jar being loaded but in [DataTables plugin page](http://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/pagination/input) itself there is no mention of this JAR.

DataTables Initialization code

```
var table = $jq11('#openCasesTable').dataTable({
    "ajax": someUrl,
    "aoColumnDefs": [
        { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [0, 6, 7] }
    ],
    "columns": [
        { 
            "data": null,
            "render": function(data, type, row, meta) {
                ...
            }
        },
        ...
    ],
    "deferRender": true,
    "dom": 'l<"#removeButtonDiv.removeButton">rtip',
    "filter": false,
    "initComplete": function(settings, json) {
        $('#removeButtonDiv').html('<input id="removeButton" type="button" value="Remove"  style="float:right; height: 25px;" disabled />');
    },
    "lengthMenu": [ [20, 40, 60, 80, 100], [20, 40, 60, 80, 100] ],
    "language": {
        "emptyTable": "No data to list",
        "infoFiltered": " "
    },
    "order": [[4, "desc"]],
    "processing": true,
    "drawCallback": function( settings ) {
        $.each(selected, function(index, value){
            $('#'+value).attr("checked", "checked");
        });
    },
    "serverSide": true,
    "sPaginationType": "input"
});
```

Comment: Can you please add a code with your usage of this plugin?

Comment: As @Eternal1 says, we need to see some code to see how you are using jQuery DataTables. You can check out the prerequisites for how to use jQuery DataTables here: http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/

Comment: Initilization code added.

Comment: I see you use `$jq11` object to initialize your `dataTable`. Do you have several `jQuery` versions on your page?

Comment: @Eternal1 - No just jQuery 1.11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From dataTable 1.10, they changed pagination structure. Now they use "paging" (Boolean), "pagingType" (String) properties, and it seems they changed the pagination plugin structure also. As a result, every pagination plugin would be not working on 1.10. You may use dataTable 1.9.

New pagination options : 
http://datatables.net/reference/option/pagingType

Pagination plugin page under construction : http://datatables.net/manual/plug-ins/paging

They provide full, simple, full_numbers, and simple_numbers as default options. If you want to use input pagination, you can download dataTable 1.9 in [their github](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/tree/1_9) or try to make own backward compatibility logic like they provided in [upgrade section](http://datatables.net/upgrade/1.10).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
      "pagingType": "full_numbers"
    } );
} );
```

Comment: Appreciate if you could post brevity initialization code.

Answer (score -1):

**HTML FILE**

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$320,800</td>
        </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

**JAVASCRIPT FILE**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable();
} );
```

Include below css as well for formatting

../../media/css/jquery.dataTables.css

All the things , sample and exmaple are there in below.you can download it.

http://www.datatables.net/download/download

Pagination with working with above things.If you still face issue can you please add file from above link and try it again.

Comment: Thank for putting the code. But I was looking to have input pagination if you understand what I mean. ;)